# How to use same User state across multiple WCF services

Tags: web-services, silverlight, authentication

I have a WCF web service that uses FormsAuthentication that logs the User into the Silverlight website. I have another web-service that needs to know what Role the user is in (e.g. Admin, User, Guest) to determine which functions that will run when called by the user from the Silverlight.

How can I pass this session state / User to the 2nd WCF web-service, or how can I get the username/password in the Silverlight application, and then pass that to the web-service to re-authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

After doing research into this, the eastiest thing appears to be have some methods in my first web service where the user logs in. From there I can check what roles they are in and if they are authenticated. If anyone has a better idea I'm eager to hear it.